# My old git commits not showing up on BitBucket, overwritten by someone else

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm working on a project with another person using git (on BitBucket)

I originally had my commits:

```
my_commit_4
my_commit_3
my_commit_2
my_commit_1
```

Now I went to check BitBucket a week later and it shows:

```
his_commit_4
his_commit_3
his_commit_2
his_commit_1
```

The `his_commit_1` encompasses all of commits `my_commit_x`, plus some of his own additions.

I tried looking at `reflog` and I still have my commits locally. I cannot pull from `origin master` because I get the following error:

```
From https://bitbucket.org/myaccount/myapp
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 + 1145d3e...fa3d2de master     -> origin/master  (forced update)
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

What exactly happened?

Is there a way to get my original commits to show in BitBucket again?

Answer (score 3):

You have unrelated histories because whoever the other person is, he *removed* your commits entirely, replacing all of them with his commits.

You can remove *his* commits and replace them with yours, tit-for-tat.  That's probably not a good strategy, but it is an option, provided you have permission to use `git push --force` (which is what he must have used to remove your commits and replace them with his).

You can merge despite the unrelated histories.  This may be easy, or hard.  To merge despite unrelated histories, use `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories`.  Git will, in effect, add a fake commit just before all of his commits, and just before all of your commits, that all of his connect to and all of yours connect to.  This fake commit is completely empty.  Therefore all the files in his last commit are new, created entirely by him; all the files in your last commit are new, created entirely by you; and Git will merge these files by taking whichever files are unique to his commit, and whichever files are unique to your commit, and declaring a merge conflict on all the remaining files that have the same name in both commits.  You'll have to hand-merge every one of those files.

He can, of course, then use `git push --force` again to discard all your work.  You probably should make sure he won't.

Ultimately, the way to resolve this is to talk with him and find out why he's discarding your commits.  It's probably unintentional, but if it is intentional, there's no *technical* solution: this is a political problem.